# Server authentication using Faye on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, faye

So I am extremely new to node.js, and faye - so I think this is pretty basic, but I'm not sure what I should be asking.

I have this setup for my faye server, running on node jitsu:

```
var http = require('http'),
    faye = require('faye');

var bayeux = new faye.NodeAdapter({mount: '/faye', timeout: 45});

// Handle non-Bayeux requests
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.write('Hello, non-Bayeux request');
  response.end();
});
bayeux.attach(server);
server.listen(8000);

var fayeToken = "myToken";

var serverAuth = {
  incoming: function(message, callback) {
    // Add an error if the tokens don't match
    if (fayeToken !== message.ext.auth_token)
        message.error = 'Invalid auth token';

      // Call the server back now we're done
      callback(message);
  }
};

bayeux.addExtension(serverAuth);
```

Then I have a rails app that connects to it.

Before I added the serverAuth stuff, it was working fine.

When I curl like so:

```
curl http://myapp.jit.su/faye -d 'message={"channel":"/alerts", "data":"hello", "ext":{"auth_token":"myToken"}}'
```

I get a success message.

In my JS file on the rails app I have:

```
$(function() {
    //FAYE CLIENT
    var faye = new Faye.Client('http://myapp.jit.su/faye');
    faye.setHeader('ext.auth_token', 'myToken');
    faye.subscribe("/alerts", function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Now I get a bad request 400 error when the rails app loads for the faye script.

The params being sent are specifically:

```
[{"channel":"/meta/handshake","version":"1.0","supportedConnectionTypes":["callback-polling"],"id":"1"}]
```

So it seems as though the header param that I'm setting isn't being sent in this "meta" handshake that faye does.

Before I had this server authentication in, it worked just fine, and I could curl messages into the app. No dice now.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference:

I had to make sure its not doing a meta call:

```
var serverAuth = {
  incoming: function(message, callback) {
    // Let non-subscribe messages through
        if (message.channel.indexOf("/meta/") !== 0){
            if (fayeToken !== message.ext.auth_token){
                message.error = 'Invalid auth token';
            }
        }   
      callback(message);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two problems here that I can see here. First, your extension will fail if the message does not have an `ext` field. You should check for it before checking `message.ext.auth_token`:

```
var serverAuth = {
    incoming: function(message, callback) {
    // Let non-subscribe messages through
        if (message.channel.indexOf("/meta/") !== 0){
            if (!message.ext || fayeToken !== message.ext.auth_token){
                message.error = 'Invalid auth token';
            }
        }   
        callback(message);
    }
};
```

I'm also not sure what you're trying to authenticate. `if (message.channel.indexOf("/meta/") !== 0)` will match any non-meta message, i.e. all messages sent with `publish()` (meta messages are used for handshaking, polling, (un)subscribing, and disconnecting). This means anyone can publish messages, but only the server can subscribe to any channels.

Second, `ext` is part of the messages themselves, whereas `setHeader()` is used to set HTTP headers, i.e. it's part of the transport layer. You should use an extension to add `ext` to messages:

```
client.addExtension({
    outgoing: function(message, callback) {
        message.ext = message.ext || {};
        message.ext.auth_token = THE_TOKEN;
        callback(message);
    }
});
```